# MAMP + Wordpress - Can't get local site to function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I have installed MAMP and am trying to get a local dev version of a Wordpress site running on my computer.

I've gone through many tutorials explaining what I need to change in `wp-config.php` and the db but I'm not able to get the page to function.

The `siteurl` & `home` fields in the db have both been updated to `http://localhost/` and I've updated `wp-config.php` for db username & password to be `root`.

I've set `WP_DEBUG: true` so that I get a bit of feedback as to what might be causing the error and the following is what I get when I try to go to `http://localhost/`:

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught Error: 
Call to undefined function mysql_error() in /Users/oldo/Desktop/Website Development/Clean Cut Concrete/mirror/public_html/cleancutconcrete.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php:29 
Stack trace: 
#0 /Users/oldo/Desktop/Website Development/Clean Cut Concrete/mirror/public_html/cleancutconcrete.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(127): UniteDBRev->checkForErrors('fetch') 
#1 /Users/oldo/Desktop/Website Development/Clean Cut Concrete/mirror/public_html/cleancutconcrete.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_params.class.php(42): UniteDBRev->fetch('wp_revslider_se...') 
#2 /Users/oldo/Desktop/Website Development/Clean Cut Concrete/mirror/public_html/cleancutconcrete.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_operations.class.php(1275): RevSliderParams->getFieldFromDB('general') 
#3 /Users/oldo/Desktop/Website Development/Clean Cut Concrete/mirror/public_html/cleancutconcrete.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_front.php(42) in /Users/oldo/Desktop/Website Development/Clean Cut Concrete/mirror/public_html/cleancutconcrete.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php on line 29
```

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to go about fixing this problem?

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been removed in PHP 7, Looks like you are using latest version of PHP on your local system. Please update your wordpress

Comment: You, my friend, are an absolute legend! I changed MAMP to use PHP 5.6.10 and it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Saqib Amin in the comments above, but I thought I'd post the answer here as well so that it's obvious. As pointed out to me, `mysql_*` functions have been removed in PHP 7, so I changed MAMP to use PHP 5.6.10 and it's now working.